# Triage/flag option for "coding request" questions

Tags: feature-request

I've doing some review queues from time to time. However, when doing the Triage queue, I sometimes encounter questions which is a "coding request". With other words, the OP doesn't even attempt to solve his/her problem themselves and is just asking for this. An example can be found on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969818/create-all-possible-combinations-from-2-tables) There are of course more worse examples...

It is not a big problem, but unfortunately, I see this kind of question being asked more frequently nowadays...

So my action is to flag it by clicking on "Unsalvageable". But I cannot really find an option which fits right on this case. Upon clicking "this should be closed" option, I see the next options

[image]

The most closest option is "too broad" (which i pick). For me this is not really the right option. Even the "off-topic" option doesn't provide a right option for "coding requests". Too broad questions are different IMHO.

Hence a proposal: **Add an extra flag option for "is a coding request" to the above option list or in the "off-topic" option list** for " *code for me pl0x* " questions. Maybe this can be useful for other flag options across this site.

Comment: I sometimes use the off-topic reason that starts with "questions seeking debugging help ... ". Because it suggests that the asker includes an MCVE. Also - downvote these things please. Get them off the front page ASAP.

Comment: I do the same as @S.L.Barth, because I once saw some mod using this as the close/put on hold reason.